# Split function add: \xef\xbb\xbf...\n to my list

Tags: python, split

I want to open my `file.txt` and split all data from this file.

Here is my `file.txt`:

```
some_data1 some_data2 some_data3 some_data4 some_data5
```

and here is my python code:

```
>>>file_txt = open("file.txt", 'r')
>>>data = file_txt.read()
>>>data_list = data.split(' ')
>>>print data
some_data1 some_data2 some_data3 some_data4 some_data5
>>>print data_list
['\xef\xbb\xbfsome_data1', 'some_data1', "some_data1", 'some_data1', 'some_data1\n']
```

As you can see here, when I print my `data_list` it adds to my list this: `\xef\xbb\xbf` and this: `\n`. What are these and how can I clean my list from them.

Thanks.

Comment: If you don't provide an argument to `str.split` it will split on all kinds of whitespace (in any combination) and as a side effect, get rid of the newline at the end of your single line file.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Your file contains [UTF-8 BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) in the beginning.

To get rid of it, first decode your file contents to unicode.

```
fp = open("file.txt")
data = fp.read().decode("utf-8-sig").encode("utf-8")
```

But better don't encode it back to `utf-8`, but work with `unicode`d text. There is a good rule: decode all your input text data to unicode as soon as possible, and work only with unicode; and encode the output data to the required encoding as late as possible. This will save you from many headaches.

To read bigger files in a certain encoding, use [`io.open`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.open) or [`codecs.open`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#codecs.open).

Also check [this](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html#reading-and-writing-unicode-data).

Use [`str.strip()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) or [`str.rstrip()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip) to get rid of the newline character `\n`.

Comment: Or open file in utf-8 mode using [`io.open`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.open).

Comment: copy the content from here: http://pastebin.com/raw/4ptxdGex do a simple search replace to remove it.

Answer (score 13):

The `\xef\xbb\xbf` is a [Byte Order Mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#Representations_of_byte_order_marks_by_encoding) for UTF-8 - the `\x` [is an escape sequence](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals) indicating the next two characters are a hex sequence representing the character code.

The `\n` is a new line character. To remove this, you can use [`rstrip()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip).

```
data.rstrip()
data_list = data.split(' ')
```

To remove the byte order mark, you can use [`io.open`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.open) (assuming you're using 2.6 or 2.7) to open the file in `utf-8` mode. Note that can be a bit slower as it's implemented in Python - if speed or older versions of Python are necessary, take a look at [`codecs.open`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#codecs.open).

Try something like this:

```
import io

# Make sure we don't lose the list when we close the file
data_list = []

# Use `with` to ensure the file gets cleaned up properly
with io.open('file.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    data = file.read() # Be careful when using read() with big files
    data.rstrip() # Chomp the newline character
    data_list = data.split(' ')

print data_list
```

Comment: I had to use `encoding='utf-8-sig'` to get this to work

Answer (score 10):

As the others mentioned, you are dealing with a file that contains UTF-8 BOM at its beginning.

They all tell you how to deal with it or removing it directly.

BUT, if you do happen to have to work with only one static file (or a small static set of them), you may wish to actively remove the BOM altogether so you simply don't have to deal with it.

As a matter of fact, most text editors will allow you to convert from one encoding to another and sometimes UTF-8 and UTF-8 with BOM are listed separately.

The first that comes to my mind (but there is many) is Notepad++. Simply go in Encoding > Convert to UTF-8 without BOM, save the file and you are set.