# csv.DictWriter returning blank strings if value is alphanumeric

Tags: python, csv

Here is the code I have:

```
import csv
import os

for root, subFolders, files in os.walk('/path/to/folder/'):
    if 'routes.csv' in files:
        with open(os.path.join(root, "R.csv"), "r") as inf, \
                open(os.path.join(root, "B.csv"), "a") as output:
            reader = csv.DictReader(inf, quotechar='"')
            headers = ["R_id"]
            writer_B_routes = csv.DictWriter(output, headers, 
                                             extrasaction='ignore')
            writer_B_routes.writeheader()
            for row in reader:
                if int(row["R_type"]) == 3:
                    writer_B_routes.writerow(row)
```

When I run this on my CSV folders, if the value of `R_id` is only numeric, then it is outputting to `B.csv` fine (ie. `1234`). However, if the value of `R_id` is alphanumeric (ie. `A123`), then the output I am getting in `B.csv` is `""`.

I have tried changing the `int(row["R_type"]) == 3` to `str()`, thinking there was some issue with how the Dialect was being built, but that did not work. I am unsure where this data is being passed only an integer.

**Update:** Link to sample data + script: [Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bw9ndy9Ac26zdE9JTW40R09QRHZUUmJxSkstajlRTGZpOEFn/edit?usp=sharing)

**Update 2:** I've tested with a few other samples - case seems to be unique, but I can't determine why. I have another sample set of data containing a `R_id` of `005M1`, and it is functioning properly. The data giving me the issue has a `R_id` of `E2` and similar. But now I know it is not for all alphanumeric ids.

Comment: Have you tried 'if "3" in str(row["R_type")' ?

Comment: Are those alphanumeric  R_id values in the CSV files (and, more to the point, in the `row` dictionary)? What happens if instead of `extrasaction='ignore'` you use `extrasaction='raise'` in the DictWriter?

Comment: @Jodgod Just tried that one, same issue. The `writer_B_routes.writerow(row) is supposed to write the value of `R_id` - somewhere along the line it seems to be rejecting these if they are alphanumeric. I also tried adding `quotechar='"'` to the `DictWriter`, but no luck.

Comment: I'd run it through a debugger to see what's happening on that `if` and what the value of `row` is (or just use print).

Comment: @PauloAlmeida The alphanumeric R_id values are in the CSV files. Changing to `raise` returned the following error: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "RemoveBAIO.py", line 18, in <module>
    writer_bus_routes.writerow(row)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/csv.py", line 148, in writerow
    return self.writer.writerow(self._dict_to_list(rowdict))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/csv.py", line 144, in _dict_to_list
    ", ".join(wrong_fields))
ValueError: dict contains fields not in fieldnames: route_long_name, route_type, agency_id, route_url, route_short_name, route_id`

Comment: An `int("A123")` will raise a `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'A123'` which would terminate your program and close `B.csv` at that point.

Comment: Also, your code only writes a row to `B.csv` when `int(row["R_type"]) == 3` (and that conditional doesn't raise a `ValueError`).

Comment: Apparently you have a special character in the beginning of routes.csv, which is screwing up the column name. When I read your file, the first column name is '\xef\xbb\xbfroute_id' instead of 'route_id'. Check [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18664712/split-function-add-xef-xbb-xbf-n-to-my-list)

Comment: @PauloAlmeida geEdit wasn't showing that additional part of the column name for me. I believe this will do it. Thank you very much!

Comment: No problem. I saw it on IPython, but now I tried it and you can actually delete the character in gedit. If you go to the beginning of the file and press the right arrow twice, the cursor only moves on the second, because the first character is the invisible one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note the following refers to your code in`RemoveBAIO.py`**not** the code shown in your question.

The problem is that the`routes.csv` file you're trying to read is a Unicode text file with a UTF-8 [Byte-Order-Mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) (or BOM) at the beginning, which is being picked-up by the`csv`module — which can't handle Unicode input in Python 2, which is noted in the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#module-csv) — as the name of the first field, so instead of the it being `"route_id"` it's `"\xef\xbb\xbfroute_id"`.

Here's a slightly modified version of your code showing the proper way to deal with files that *might* have an initial BOM. It does this by using`codecs.open()`in conjunction with`'utf-8-sig'`encoding. This encoding is described in the [*Encodings and Unicode*](http://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#encodings-and-unicode) section of the documentation for the `codecs`module. When decoding this will skip over any BOM present and on encoding it will first write the 3-byte BOM sequence. In the code below it's intentionally only used for reading the input file (I explain why further down). The effect is that the first field name in the input file doesn't get messed-up.

Also note I removed the conversion to`int`in the `'route_type'`check so it wouldn't raise a `ValueError`exception if it encounter one with non-numeric characters in it.

The`bus_route_ids.csv`will *not* have a leading BOM on it. Adding one would be complicated because it's possible that data will be appended to it, so adding the BOM would have to be conditional on whether the file already existed or not. FWIW, I also noticed that the`routes.csv`is not a proper UTF-8 because it has a `\xa0` character embedded on the last line which has an ordinal value greater than 128.

```
import codecs
import csv
import os

path_to_folder = '/insert/path/'

with open('hasfares.txt', 'w') as hf:
    for root, subFolders, files in os.walk(path_to_folder):
        if 'fare_rules.csv' in files:
            hf.write('%s\n' % root)

        if 'routes.csv' in files:
            routes_path = os.path.join(root, 'routes.csv')
            bus_route_ids_path = os.path.join(root, 'bus_route_ids.csv')
            appending_to_existing_file = os.path.exists(bus_route_ids_path)
            with codecs.open(routes_path, 'r', 'utf-8-sig') as inf, \
                    open(os.path.join(root, "bus_route_ids.csv"), "a") as output:
                reader = csv.DictReader(inf, quotechar='"')
                headers = ['route_id']
                writer_bus_routes = csv.DictWriter(output, headers,
                                                   extrasaction='ignore')
                if not appending_to_existing_file:
                    writer_bus_routes.writeheader()
                for row in reader:
                    if row['route_type'] == '3':
                        writer_bus_routes.writerow(row)
```

Resulting `bus_route_ids.csv` file (assuming it did not already exist):

```
route_id
E1
E2
N
N1
N2
N3
170
S1
S2
S3
S4
W1
W2
W3
W4
C
```

Comment: @T.Mount: Does this not answer your question?

Comment: Had moved on using Paulo's comments above - but your solution is more easily applied over my data set. Thanks again!

Comment: @T.Mount: I updated my answer to show the proper, as in not-a-hack, way to handle BOMs -- which I just recently learned about myself here on SO. Happy New Year.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
row["R_type"] == "3"
```

If R_type is alphanumeric then it's type is string. Whereas 3 is an int.

Python doesn't implicitly parse the int value 3 to a string and doing an == comparison between a string and an int will always return false. To fix it you'll to either use the the string version "3" or cast 3 to a string str(3).

If R_type can be parsed from CSV as either an int or a string you should also add an explicit cast to always force to string so you don't get any false negatives.

For example:

```
str(row["R_type"]) == "3"
```

Comment: I have attempted both instances of this, still returning `""` as R_id

Comment: It's impossible to see what is breaking it without a sample of the data.

Comment: Uploading to Dropbox - will post a link in main question body.