# Unknown characters in column name

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df like this:

```
Allotments   NDWI   TWI
1             2     4
2             3     6
```

and I am trying to rename the columns, but when I print:

```
df.columns.values
```

this is returned:

```
['\xef\xbb\xbfAllotments' 'NDWI' 'TWI']
```

when I look at the df it just says `Allotments` though.  How can I remove those extra characters?

I tried

```
df.rename(columns=lambda x: x.strip())
```

but no luck.

Comment: The extra characters are the utf8 BOM. See this stackoverflow answer for further details. http://stackoverflow.com/a/18664752/1977847

Comment: It's a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#Representations_of_byte_order_marks_by_encoding) utf-8 I believe

Comment: How are you reading this data in? If it's by `read_csv` then try pass `encoding='utf-8'`

Comment: wouldn't a simple str() on the values work?

Comment: @user2255757 No, that wouldn't work.

Comment: @Goodies thanks, didn't know that

Comment: @EdChum, thanks works great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass `encoding='utf-8'` to [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv) as a kwarg so it decodes the BOM correctly.

Answer (score 0):

This is a [UTF-8 Byte Order Mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). You can de-re-encode the contents to fix this.

```
x = ['\xef\xbb\xbfAllotments', 'NDWI', 'TWI']
x = [s.decode("utf-8-sig").encode("utf-8") for s in x]
print(x) # => ['Allotments', 'NDWI', 'TWI']
```