# invalid start byte while decoding url to utf-8-sig

Tags: python, web-scraping

Following is the code:

```
for page in forumPages:
    try:
        req = Request(page, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
        sock = urlopen(req).read().decode("utf-8-sig")
        soup = BeautifulSoup(sock, 'html.parser')
        pageThreads = soup.findAll('ol',{"class":"threads"})
        print(len(pageThreads))

    except Exception as ex:
        pass
```

I'm getting error as 
`invalid start byte`

How to solve the exception so i can have valid text to apply SOUP.

Doing `urlopen(req).read()` gives `\xef\xbb\xbf<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC ...`

Page im trying is `https://www.siasat.pk/forum/forumdisplay.php?22-Siasi-Discussion/page1`

I have tried applying [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18664712/split-function-add-xef-xbb-xbf-n-to-my-list): 
`sock = urlopen(req).read().decode("utf-8-sig").encode("utf-8")` but exception is the same

Comment: i tried applying the solution, but the exception is the same

Comment: WHERE is the invalid start byte that you are getting an exception about? The problem doesn't seem to be at the start of the code; but later on it might not be valid utf-8.

Comment: There are some funny opening quotation marks in the text around position 166300. Try `urlopen(req).read().decode("utf-8-sig","ignore")`.

Comment: @alexis solution worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The start of the file you show does appear to be a UTF-8 version of the unicode byte order mark, so your decoding approach is correct. Apparently the rest of the file contains invalid utf-8 somewhere. Since you don't control the quality of the input you are scraping, you could suppress the error like this so you can carry on:

```
text = urlopen(req).read().decode("utf-8-sig", errors="replace")
```

This will replace problem areas with a special symbol, so you can see where the problem arose. Or use `errors="ignore"` to make them just go away.