# How do I remove 'b'\xef\xbb\xbf' from my data table array?

Tags: python, arrays, encoding, decoding

I'm a beginner with `Python` and trying to use an `array`.

However after importing and displaying I get `'b'\xef\xbb\xbf'` by the first value (1,1) and b' in front on all int values in col 1.

How can these be removed? Is it a decoding/encoding issue?

I'm using `python 3.5`

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
 x = np.genfromtxt('file.txt',dtype=None)

df = pd.DataFrame(x)

print(df)
```

This outputs:

```
b'\xef\xbb\xbf1850' -0.274
b'1851' -0.271
...
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Split function add: \xef\xbb\xbf...\n to my list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18664712/split-function-add-xef-xbb-xbf-n-to-my-list)

Comment: can you post a sample of the data in file.txt?

Comment: From the numpy documentation for genfromtext, the default encoding used is bytes so decoding will be required - https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html

Answer (score 0):

Change this line - `x = np.genfromtxt('file.txt',dtype=None)` to

```
x = np.genfromtxt('file.txt',dtype=None, encoding=None)
```

This will make it use your system default encoding. If that does not output readable text, replace 'None' with 'utf-8'

Answer (score 0):

This extra data is the BOM, which is not really supposed to be there. It indicates that the file is UTF-8. Python calls this encoding `utf-8-sig`, so use this:

```
x = np.genfromtxt('file.txt', dtype=None, encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

Comment: doing that gives the error message..
    TypeError: genfromtxt() got an unexpected keyword argument 'encoding'

Comment: What version of NumPy? It’s in the docs: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html