# Python: Trouble turning a string into an int

Tags: python, python-2.x

While I know that in python (using v2) it is very simple to turn a string into an integer, and many times I have used the int() method. But I am now working with a file whose string seems to be a little more complicated, and I don't know how to work with it.

In general, I've learned that the repr() method is useful, so I used that to try and figure out what going on with my_string, using this code (with some other useful checks).

```
print my_string
print type(my_string)
print repr(my_string)
print repr('1')
```

And this is the output:

```
1
<type 'str'>
'\xef\xbb\xbf1'
'1'
```

So clealy I am working with a string, and clearly it prints to a "1", yet the repr() returns something else completely, and this seems to inhibit the int() method, which right now returns this:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\xef\xbb\xbf1'
```

How can I convert this to an int?

Comment: what python version is this?

Comment: @ParitoshSingh 2, judging by the `print` keyword

Comment: `'\xef\xbb\xbf1'` BOM header.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18664712/split-function-add-xef-xbb-xbf-n-to-my-list it seems related.

Comment: `'\xef\xbb\xbf'` is an encoding abomination, a UTF-8 BOM. You pretty much just have to replace it out when some tool inserts it by mistake. `int(my_string.decode('utf-8').replace(u'\ufeff', u''))`, for example.

Answer (score 0):

That is a Byte-Order Marker, encoded using UTF-8.

You won't see that while printing, because it's a technical marker of the byte structure.

Where did that file come from? You should ideally fix it so it doesn't write a BOM, as they are useless with UTF-8. To strip it, you can replace it with emptyness and then cast it to an int:

```
>>> int(my_string.replace('\xef\xbb\xbf', ''))
1
```