# AWS Lambda Python 3 handle POST file

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, file, aws-lambda

I'm working with Python 3.8 on AWS Lambda, and I would like to handle posted file, like `requests.files` with Django. But it's impossible with AWS Lambda. I want to put this file in the S3 with :

```
s3.put_object(
    Body=fileAsString,
    Bucket=MY_BUCKET,
    Key='my-file.jpg'
)
```

When I return directly the received event, with the file :

[image]

First try : with `cgi.parse_multipart` :
I my handler :

```
c_type, c_data = parse_header(event['headers']['Content-Type'])
boundary = c_data['boundary'].encode('latin1')
body = event['body'].encode('utf8')

fp = BytesIO(body)
pdict = {
    'boundary': boundary,
    'CONTENT-LENGTH': str(len(body))
}
form_data = parse_multipart(fp, pdict)
fileBytes: bytes = form_data['file'][0]
return ({'statusCode': 200, 'body': json.dumps(str(fileBytes))}
```

I receive :[image]
I also tried with `form_data['file'][0].decode('utf-8')` but I receive : [image] and I have always the "?"

I should get this, because it's the original image, opened in edition :
[image]

Second try : I follow this tutorial : https://medium.com/swlh/upload-binary-files-to-s3-using-aws-api-gateway-with-aws-lambda-2b4ba8c70b8e

So, I tried :

```
file_content = base64.b64decode(event['body'])
```

but I get :

```
string argument should contain only ASCII characters
```

(the same with `validate=False`)
and when I try to load body as dict with :

```
body2 = json.loads(event['body'])
```

I get :

```
loads failed : Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

I tried to add "image/png" and "image/*" to "Binary Media Types" in the settings of the API, but no change.

Any idea ?

Comment: Did you found the solution  ?

Comment: No, I gave up...

Answer (score 4):

This is an old post but I was going crazy trying to solve it.

It turns out that the solution for me was to add ALL binary types to the API Gateway as so:
[image: AWS API Gateway settings]

My issue was that my code was working for a .png file but not a .jpg file.
Once the correct MIME type was added "image/jpeg" all worked OK and the Error

```
string argument should contain only ASCII characters
```

went away.
NOTE: that the API needs to be re-deployed after this change (which is not instantaneous)

Bottom line: this code is my working code:

```
import json
import boto3
import base64
  
s3 = boto3.client('s3')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
if event['httpMethod'] == 'POST' : 
    fileName = event['multiValueQueryStringParameters']['fileName']
    bodyData = event['body']
    decodedFile = base64.b64decode(bodyData)
    s3.put_object(Bucket=<BUCKET_NAME>, Key=fileName[0], Body=decodedFile)
    return {'statusCode': 200, 
        'body': json.dumps({'message': 'file saved successfully'}), 
        'headers': {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'}}
```

Comment: To add here, in my case the POST request Content-Type header was set to form-data. So adding multipart/form-datato Binary media type, resolved my issue. However, all the other form data is lost when the gateway converts into binary.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `requests.files`, it will upload images as multipart. It's a standard way to upload multiple content-type files at once but you'll need to parse it when receive.
If your application is not sensitive with content-type, just use `base64` enc/dec to post and receive like below pseudo code:

Uploader:

```python
import json
import requests
import base64

with open("/path/to/your/file/image.png", "rb") as image_file:
        encoded_string = base64.b64encode(image_file.read())

    payload = {
                'name': 'image.png',
                'file': encoded_string.decode('utf-8')
                }

    url = 'https://api_url/upload'
    r = requests.post(url, data = json.dumps(payload), headers = {})
```

Lambda side:

```python
import json
import boto3
import base64

def upload(event, context):
    body = json.loads(event['body'])

    s3 = boto3.client("s3", region_name='us-east-1')

    decodedFile = base64.b64decode(body['file'])
    rs = s3.put_object(
                        Bucket='bucket_name',
                        Key=body['name'],
                        Body=decodedFile
                        )

    response = {
        "statusCode": 200,
    }

    return response
```

Answer (score 0):

```
upload_file = request.files['file']
img = re.sub(b"\xef\xbf\xbd", b'', upload_file.stream.read())
```

when i upload to the flask, the AWS Lambda add UTF-8 BOM,this is just a trick to cleanup utf-8 bom bytes, it works fine for me.

[split-function-add-xef-xbb-xbf-n-to-my-list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18664712/split-function-add-xef-xbb-xbf-n-to-my-list)

Comment: Can you add some explanations ?

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was to do:

```
event['body'] = str(event['body']).encode('utf-8)
```